# Is the set of nilpotents of a Lie algebra a Lie subalgebra?

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}\subset gl(V)$ be a Lie algebra. Is the set of nilpotents of $\mathfrak{g}$ a lie subalgebra? To be more precise, let $A$ and $B$ be nilpotent matrices. Then is $AB-BA$ also nilpotent?

Comment: It's true in finite-dimensional **solvable** Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ (assuming the field has characteristic zero).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$.

Comment: Thanks. A proof in my Lie algebra textbook says "consider the lie subalgebra consisting of all the nilpotent elements". Is it just the algebra generated by all the nilpotent elements?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Which book? Which Lie algebra?